# How to change characters in a file?

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains many characters. I need to count how many times each character
is shown in the file (The file contains more than one `" "` between each word).
I figured that the best way to do so is using    `tr -s " " "/n"`
and then using `sort`. That way I can easily use `egerp -c` to count the characters.

But how do i use the tr command properly?
I seem to be unable to use it and put it into a variable.

Comment: This really sounds like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Give an example of the sort of input you have, and exactly what information you'd like to extract from it.

Comment: Its not clear if you are looking for a particular word or you are looking out for all the words in a file? What's there in your input file?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.I'm supposed to read a file-name and check how many times each character is found in the file.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest implementation would probably be to add a `\n` after each char,
then to sort them and count them:

```
$ cat file
foo bar baz.
$ sed 's/./&\n/g' file | sort | uniq -c
      1 
      2  
      1 .
      2 a
      2 b
      1 f
      2 o
      1 r
      1 z
```

You can probably do something like that with bash's associative arrays, but it would be tricky and you couldn't count `\0` characters anyway.

Comment: I'm a bit new to bash...can you please explain line 2? (foo bar baz.)

Answer (score 1):

Using sed in regular expression mode may help you If I understood your problem correctly

```
sed -r 's/(.){1}/\1\n/g' your_file.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

You tell sed to capture any character that appears once with a regexp group ( the (.){1} part ) and the substitute it by the group ( \1 ) and then put \n to have one per line. Next, you can use sort and uniq -c to make that count for you. This will include non-printable characters, you can avoid counting non-printable characters by introducing some changes in the sed:

```
sed -r 's/[^[[:graph:]]]*//g;s/([[:graph:]]){1}/\1\n/g' your_file.txt | sort -n | uniq -c
```

First delete non-printable characters and the substitute printable characters by itself plus \n